# Add item in SharePoint 2010 document library using JavaScript

Tags: 2010, javascript, client-object-model

Is it possible to add a new item in a SharePoint 2010 **document** library using JavaScript (client object model)? I have successfully created list items in other type of lists, but when it comes to uploading a document I'm out of luck. Maybe this is a feature only supported in SharePoint 2013?

Edit: This is a working example how I add an item to a custom list. I'd like to do something similar using a document library.

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContexturl);
var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('ProjectData');

clientContext.load(list);

var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
var listItem = list.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

listItem.set_item('Title', 'My project title!');
listItem.update();

clientContext.load(listItem);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onItemAdded, onItemAddedFailed);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using this code:

```
// Getting a reference to the document library 
var sp = new SPSite("http://localhost"); 
var site = sp.OpenWeb(); 
var folder = site.GetFolder("Documents"); 
var files = folder.Files;

// Opening a filestream 
var fStream = File.OpenRead("C:MyDocument.docx"); 
var contents = new byte[fStream.Length]; 
fStream.Read(contents, 0, (int)fStream.Length); 
fStream.Close();

// Adding any metadata needed 
var documentMetadata = new Hashtable {{"Comments", "Hello World"}};

// Adding the file to the SPFileCollection 
var currentFile = 
    files.Add("Documents/MyDocument.docx", contents, documentMetadata, true);

site.Dispose(); 
sp.Dispose();
```

[link to source](http://zimmergren.net/technical/how-to-upload-a-filedocument-using-the-sharepoint-object-model)
Using client object:

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://spdevinwin");
Web web = context.Web;
FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Work\Files\17580_FAST2010_S05_Administration.pptx");
newFile.Url = "17580_FAST2010_S05_Administration 4MB file uploaded via client OM.pptx";
List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
context.Load(uploadFile);
context.ExecuteQuery();
 Console.WriteLine("done");
```

[link to source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2010/03/12/uploading-files-using-client-object-model-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

Using Java Script:

```
function createFile(resultpanel) {
    var clientContext;
    var oWebsite;
    var oList;
    var fileCreateInfo;
    var fileContent;

    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
    oList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle("Shared Documents");

    fileCreateInfo = new SP.FileCreationInformation();
    fileCreateInfo.set_url("my new file.txt");
    fileCreateInfo.set_content(new SP.Base64EncodedByteArray());
    fileContent = "The content of my new file";

    for (var i = 0; i < fileContent.length; i++) {

        fileCreateInfo.get_content().append(fileContent.charCodeAt(i));
    }

    this.newFile = oList.get_rootFolder().get_files().add(fileCreateInfo);

    clientContext.load(this.newFile);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, successHandler),
        Function.createDelegate(this, errorHandler)
    );

    function successHandler() {
        resultpanel.innerHTML =
            "Go to the " +
            "<a href='../Lists/Shared Documents'>document library</a> " +
            "to see your new file.";
    }

    function errorHandler() {
        resultpanel.innerHTML = "Request failed: " + arguments[1].get_message();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. However, I assume this is server based code. I don't think using a file stream is possible. My goal is to upload a file using JavaScript.

Comment: Please look at this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2010/03/12/uploading-files-using-client-object-model-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: Sorry, I've tried this specific code already but it doesn't work. I cannot even create a FileCreationInformation object. This code will be put in a Content Editor webpart if that might be the problem?

Comment: I update the code with java script solution

Comment: The SP.FileCreationInformation type wasn't included in the JavaScript Client Object Model in SharePoint 2010

Comment: @Rob Windsor: Meaning it's not possible uploading a file using SharePoint 2010 and javascript? Many thanks anyway, I really appreciate all help.